# xml data parse and display it on a UITableview

Tags: xml-parsing, uitableview

Please anybody help me. i want to display the particular attribute and its value of xml data into an UItableView. but i do not know how can i do that.i have no problem to parse the xml data and already i have done it in console but i am becoming unable to display these data in UITableview or any UIView using particular attribute name and value of the attribute from xml...Here is my xml data...

```
`
<list>
<ProductData HASH="1892201664">
<id>1</id>
<productNumber>a91cc0f4c7</productNumber>
<name>Product 1</name>
<seoTitle>product-1</seoTitle>
<viewCount>0</viewCount>
<availableStock>100.0</availableStock>
<lowStock>0.0</lowStock>
<image>5e928bbae358c93caedf6115fa7d178b.jpg</image>
<basePrice>10.0</basePrice>
<costPrice>0.0</costPrice>
<height>1.0</height>
<width>1.0</width>
<depth>1.0</depth>
<weight>2.0</weight>
<status>A</status>
<quantityOrderMin>1.0</quantityOrderMin>
<productIsCall>false</productIsCall>
<quantityOrderMax>20.0</quantityOrderMax>
<orderCount>0</orderCount>
<sortOrder>1</sortOrder>
<isFreeShipping>false</isFreeShipping>
<productIsFree>false</productIsFree>
<isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
<priceByAttribute>false</priceByAttribute>
<dateCreated>2011-10-06T16:08:45</dateCreated>
<dateUpdated>2011-10-06T10:08:45</dateUpdated>
<isDummy>true</isDummy>
<isInventory>false</isInventory>
</ProductData>`
```

Please help me.i am in serious trouble.if anybody can please send source code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pragma mark tableview

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

int sectionCount = [records count];
NSLog(@"section cout: %d",sectionCount);
return sectionCount;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    cellView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,8,290, 120)] autorelease];
    cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cellView.tag =10;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 40, 48, 48)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"productbox.png"];
    imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    imgView.tag = 5;
    [cellView addSubview:imgView];

    CGRect idLabelRect = CGRectMake(65, 0, 190, 18);
    idLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:idLabelRect] autorelease];
    idLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    idLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    idLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    idLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    idLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    idLabel.tag = 0;

    CGRect statusRect = CGRectMake(65, 22, 190, 22);
    statusLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusRect] autorelease];
    statusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    statusLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    statusLabel.tag = 1;

    CGRect orderDateRect = CGRectMake(65, 48, 190, 22);
    orderDate = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:orderDateRect] autorelease];
    orderDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    orderDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    orderDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    orderDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    orderDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    orderDate.tag = 2;

    CGRect byRect = CGRectMake(65, 75, 190, 22);
    byLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:byRect] autorelease];
    byLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    byLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    byLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    byLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    byLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    byLabel.tag = 3;

    CGRect totalRect = CGRectMake(65, 98, 190, 22);
    totalLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:totalRect] autorelease];
    totalLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    totalLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    totalLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    totalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    totalLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    totalLabel.tag = 4;

    [cellView addSubview:idLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:statusLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:orderDate];
    [cellView addSubview:byLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:totalLabel];
}

//for removing overlapping problem

cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
idLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:0];
statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];
orderDate = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:2];
byLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:3];
totalLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:4];
imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];


    //records is an mutable array which also containing a nsarray.

idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Id: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0]];
statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
orderDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:2]];
byLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:3]];
totalLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:4]];

return cell;
 }
```